# Grab specific API data under a button javascript

Tags: javascript, api, data-retrieval

I have a search bar and button "Search" returning data from the Tesco Labs API. The API has four parameters: query, searchTerm, offset, and limit.

I want to have a button "Bread" where it displays bread only as a query. So if a user clicks the button then bread products will display instead of having to search for the term in the search bar. The following is the working code i have for the search bar and search button. I have tried to modify this for the bread button to return bread products only but am having no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get a reference to the get button.
  var button = $('#buttonGet');

  button.click(function() {
    button.text('Getting product...');

searchForProducts($('#textSearch').val(), function(data) {
  button.text('Search');
  console.log(data);
  if (data.uk.ghs.products.results.length = 0) {
    $('#data').html(createResultsMarkup(data.uk.ghs.products.results));
  } else {
    $('#data').html('No products returned');
  }
  });
 });

function createResultsMarkup(results) {
  var resultsMarkup = "";
  $.each(results, function(index, product) {

resultsMarkup = resultsMarkup + 
"<img src=" + product.image + ">" + "" + "</img>" +
"<h3>" + product.name + "</h2>" +
"<h4>" + product.department + "</h4>" +
"<h4>" + product.price + "euro" + "</h4>";
});

  var markup = "<ul>" + resultsMarkup + "</ul>";
  return markup;
}

function searchForProducts(searchTerm, dataReturned) {
   var params = {
    query: searchTerm,
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
     };
```

Comment: What did you tried yourself?

Comment: The code provided wouldn't compile. You're missing curly bracket(s).